# Implicit class in companion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I thought implicits in the companion object would be found.  What's wrong with this?

```
object Elsewhere{
    case class NamedInt(i: Int, name: String)
    object NamedInt{
        implicit class ToNamedInt(i: Int){
            def named(name: String) = NamedInt(i, name)
        }
    }
}

object Application{
    import Elsewhere.NamedInt

    //Error: value named is not a member of Int
    val named: NamedInt = 3.named("bob") 
}
```

**Update**: I realise I can import the implicit class directly, but I thought it should compile without it since the implicit is in the companion object.  E.g. this works without an extra import

```
object Elsewhere{
    case class MyInt(i: Int)
    object MyInt{
        import scala.language.implicitConversions
        implicit def myIntToSome(t: MyInt): Some[Int] = Some(t.i)
    }

}

object Application{
    import Elsewhere.MyInt

    val o: Option[Int] = MyInt(1) 
}
```

**Update 2**:

[Jesse Eichar comments on his blog](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/companion-object-implicits.html?showComment=1272184585326#c5743584945051759597):

> You are confusing implicit parameter resolution with implicit object
>   conversion. Implicit object conversion is potentially dangerous so
>   they normally have to be imported explicitly into scope.
>
> Caveats to that is implicit object conversions defined in superclasses
>   and (I am pretty sure) in package objects are automatically in scope.

This would make sense to me, but then why does the `MyInt` example above work?

Answer (score 2):

Adding one extra line fixes things (you need to also explicitly import the companion object fields):

```
object Application{
    import Elsewhere.NamedInt
    import Elsewhere.NamedInt._

    // Compiles OK now :)
    val named: NamedInt = 3.named("bob")
}
```

Comment: That's been my workaround, but I thought it would work without since the implicit is in the companion object.  Have added update with a similar thing that works.